# How to remove Ubuntu 17.04 which is there along with 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, dell-vostro

I have updated my ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 . But the update failed and 17.04 is not working. So I decided to restore 16.04 which is given by Dell-vostro. When the restore is done, grub is showing both 16.04 and 17.04. I want to remove 17.04 completely from my PC. So what should I do ?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? You need to make sure correct install is the version of grub you are using. If 16.04 is first entry in grub, then you have correct version of grub as default whether UEFI or BIOS. Best to see details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info